# How to know base version of dojo on custom built

Tags: javascript, dojo

We have an application which was running on old dojo version. It was a custom built on top of one of older version. We are getting 0.0.0 dev as dojo version which indicates custom built.
Can you please help us find the base version of custom built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be know based on dojo library(bootstarp.js) which contains version of dojo.